# reCaptcha V3 не присылает токен

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Решил перейти на новомодную третью версию рекаптчи от google, но столкнулся с проблемой. Когда выполняю этот скрипт в Chrome на ПК и на телефоне, то в ответ получаю токен.

```
grecaptcha.execute("мой_публичный_ключ", {action: "signin"})
.then((token) => {
    console.log(token)
});
```

Но в Safari на iOS и в Samsung Internet в ответ получаю `Object {then:function function}`

[image: ОТВЕТ В ХРОМЕ]
[image: ОТВЕТ В SAMSUNG INTERNET]

Что именно я делаю не так?
Если Samsung Internet работает на движке Chromium, то почему в Хроме на телефоне таких проблем не возникает?

P.S. Инспектирую Samsung Internet через USB внутри Хрома

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался сам. В SI токен приходит только на сайты с httpS. Скорей всего проблема в самом браузере, т.к. в хроме на телефоне токен приходит и на http. Соответственно, проблема решается переходом на https.

Answer (score 0):

Некоторые браузеры могут не поддерживать стрелочные функции. Попробуйте так:

```
grecaptcha.execute("мой_публичный_ключ", {action: "signin"})
.then(function(token){
     console.log(token)
});
```

Comment: Не, уже пробовал, со стрелочными все хорошо в SI